# Drop-down input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a similar drop-down input field (picture below), to my website. I want it to appear when a link/image/button is clicked on. Can this be done with JavaScript? Also, I don't want it to affect the flow of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be done with JavaScript?

Yes. The JavaScript/CSS equivalent would be a button which (when clicked) displayed an element with `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`.

Here is a simple example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/Byujd/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complex.

### HTML & Default Styles

You need an element which is displayed above the content:

```
<div class="modal">
  <!-- Some content like textarea and stuff -->
</div>
```

Now you can style this box with the `position`-property and other things:

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

This now displays above the rest of the content.

### Some jQuery-Goodness

The button just needs a listener. With jQuery this looks something like this:

```
$('.the-buttons-class').click( function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.modal').toggle();
});
```

### A better way

Instead of toggling the state of the modal with jQuery's `toggle()`-function you could toggle a class on it and manipulate the state accordingly:

CSS:

```
.modal {
  ...
  display: none;
}

.modal.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.the-buttons-class').click( function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.modal').toggleClass('shown');
});
```

### Moar

I've done something pretty similar at [my page](http://drublic.de/blog/). Make sure to check the search box.
The code for it is [on GitHub](https://github.com/drublic/drublic-blog).